# Vue2: Re-use same instance of component across 2 parent components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got a `<MyVideo>` player that needs to be a child of a `<section-1>` component. After the user is done with section 1, the *same instance* of the video needs to continue being used inside the `<section-2>` component. Is there a way to re-use the same instance of this video player across parents?

#### Approach 1:

This will initiate a new instance of `<MyVideo>`, so everything resets when changing sections, which is not what I need.

```html
<section-1 :v-if="page === 1">
   <MyVideo>
</section-1>
<section-2 :v-if="page === 2">
   <MyVideo>
</section-2>
```

#### Approach 2:

I also tried passing the vidPlayer as a property, but it gives me [TypeError: cyclic object value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value) error. Probably because it tries to convert the component into a JSON object.

```html
<MyVideo ref="vidPlayer">
<section-1 :v-if="page === 1" :video="$refs.vidPlayer"></section-1>
<section-2 :v-if="page === 2" :video="$refs.vidPlayer"></section-2>
```

Are there any options so I can re-use the *same instance* of the video player within 2 separate components?

(The video player is pretty complex and uses WebGL, so I can only initiate one per page for continuity and performance reasons)

Comment: "the same instance of the video" - the instance of what? An instance of a component can't be reused. If there is some object that needs to be reused then it's up to the implementation, which is unknown

Comment: What for do you need player `:video="$refs.vidPlayer"` in your section component?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your player in a `v-if`, then it will be recreated with every switch, which is not desired behavior.

If you try to use `v-show` instead of `v-if`, then you will have several hidden instances of the player.

I would suggest you to rethink your design around your requirement. If the video player should have only one instance on the page, then you should build your app around this instance.

Your intention with sections is not described detailed enough to provide you with good solutions. What about to put your section data around the player and change them with every new section?

I think you can also use Vue `slots` gut for this purpose.